# Vue.js keep-alive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Помогите разобраться с keep-alive.

На данный момент все роуты обернуты в keep-alive:

```
<keep-alive>
     <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

Сделано это намеренно, чтобы кэшировать компоненты при переходе с одного на другой.

Но среди всех этих компонентов, есть один, для которого такое поведение нежелательно. Можно ли каким-то образом сделать исключение для него?

Answer (score 2):

Читайте документацию, пожалуйста - https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Каждый ваш компонент имеет имя. Пропишите это имя в `exclude`.